# Strange behavior from HTTP authentication with suds SOAP library

Tags: python, suds

I have a working python program that is fetching a large volume of data via SOAP using suds.  The web service is implemented with a paging function such that I can grab *nnn* rows with each fetch call and grab the next *nnn* with subsequent calls.  If I authenticate to the HTTP server with code like the following

```
client = suds.client.Client(url=url, location=location, username=username, password=password, timeout=timeout)
```

everything works great.  If, however, I use the following

```
t = suds.transport.https.HttpAuthenticated(username=username, password=password)
t.handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(t.pm)
t.urlopener = urllib2.build_opener(t.handler)
client = suds.client.Client(url=url, location=location, timeout=timeout, transport=t)
```

it works for exactly 6 iterations.  That is if I specify a fetch limit of 10 rows per fetch, I get back 60 rows.  On the seventh fetch, I receive

```
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/client.py", line 649, in send
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/suds/client.py", line 698, in failed
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be causing this.  It is definitely this change that is causing the problem.  I can swap authentication styles back and forth and it is completely reproducible.

I am running python 2.6.6 with suds 0.4.

Thanks

Comment: Any progress with this? If I pass wrong authentication data to the constructor, I get the same error instead of an exception. If I use HttpAuthenticated to connect and pass that to the suds client constructor, I always get 403 Bad request (invalid authentication) even if the authentication data is valid.

Answer (score 10):

The problem seems to be that an `urllib2.HTTPError` is being raised from a lower level, and its `fp` attribute is None:

Line 81 in `suds.transport.http`:

```
except u2.HTTPError, e:
    if e.code in (202,204):
        result = None
    else:
        raise TransportError(e.msg, e.code, e.fp)
```

That exception eventually gets passed to line 698 in `suds.client` where that `error.fp.read()` line blows up:

```
def failed(self, binding, error):
    status, reason = (error.httpcode, tostr(error))
    reply = error.fp.read()
```

I'd suggest monkey-patching the `suds.SoapClient` class to get the HTTP error code and message. Add these lines before you construct your `suds.Client`, then run it to see what HTTP error the 7th fetch raises:

```
class TestClient(suds.client.SoapClient):
    def failed(self, binding, error):
        print error.httpcode, error.args

suds.client.SoapClient = TestClient
```

Comment: On the 7'th execution of the fetch call, I received "401 ('basic auth failed',), None".  If I pass the username and password to the client constructor, I receive no such error.

Comment: Maybe do a lower-level urllib2 debug to make sure your transport/handelrs are being used on that 7th pass. Suds might be switching back to using its default transport for some reason, which fails when no user/pass are provided.

Comment: I used your patch but instead of the `print..`, I used `raise error` and everything worked as expected. Thanks!