# Python SOAP client, WSDL call with suds gives Transport Error 401 Unauthorized for HTTP basic authentication

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, basic-authentication, suds

### Background

I'm building a SOAP client with python 2.7.3 and using the suds 0.4.1 library provided by Canonical. The server is using basic authentication over HTTPS.

### Problem

Can't pass authentication on the server, even to get at the WSDL. I get the following error:

> suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

### Attempts at resolution and code

I have tried both of the authentication methods described in the [suds documentation](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#Basic), but still get the error above at the `client = Client(url, ...)` line. I've confirmed the credentials and ability to connect in a web browser, which works fine.

After declaring `wsdl_url`, `username` and `password`, I tried:

```
client = Client(url=wsdl_url, username=username, password=password)

# as well as:

t = HttpAuthenticated(username=username, password=password)
client = Client(url=wsdl_url, transport=t)

# and even:

t = HttpAuthenticated(username=username, password=password)
t.handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(t.pm)
t.urlopener = urllib2.build_opener(t.handler)
client = Client(url=wsdl_url, transport=t)
```

That last one seems to, at least, get a response from the WSDL URL in [another question about HTTP authentication with suds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201037/strange-behavior-from-http-authentication-with-suds-soap-library).

### Other notes

This question is distinct from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697210/python-suds-soap-request-to-https-service-401) because I am using:

```
from suds.transport.https import HttpAuthenticated
# not:
# from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
```

and from the Traceback, the `client = Client(url, ...)` call clearly hits suds.transport.https.py:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 112, in __init__ self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/reader.py", line 152, in open d = self.fn(url, self.options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 136, in __init__ d = reader.open(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/reader.py", line 79, in open d = self.download(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/reader.py", line 95, in download fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 60, in open return  HttpTransport.open(self, request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 64, in open raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: +1 for well explained question. could we have a look at the full traceback? also, sorry if this sound patronising, but are you sure you are using the correct username & password for the service

Comment: @olly_uk I added more of the traceback. The preceding line will vary depending on which version of the `client = Client(url=wsdl_url ...)` I use. I was convinced it had to be a mistake with the username and password, too, but I copy-and-pasted straight from the config file into the browser (multiple times!) to make absolutely sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

suds wasn't adding the authorization header to the request, so I set it manually:

```
import base64

# code excluded for brevity

base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
authenticationHeader = {
    "SOAPAction" : "ActionName",
    "Authorization" : "Basic %s" % base64string
}
client = Client(url=wsdl_url, headers=authenticationHeader)
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same 401: Unauthorized issue using this method. :(

Comment: Not sure why this was selected as an answer. I'm still facing exact same 401:Unauthorized error, even after base64 encoding:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63545453/error-suds-transport-transporterror-http-error-401-unauthorized-using-suds-p 
as also mentioned by user @SomeGuyOnAComputer

Answer (score 0):

You can used SOAPpy

```
import SOAPpy, base64

class myHTTPTransport(SOAPpy.HTTPTransport):
    username = None
    passwd = None

    @classmethod
    def setAuthentication(cls,u,p):
        cls.username = u
        cls.passwd = p

    def call(self, addr, data, namespace, soapaction=None, encoding=None, http_proxy=None, config=SOAPpy.Config, timeout=None):

        if not isinstance(addr, SOAPpy.SOAPAddress):
          addr = SOAPpy.SOAPAddress(addr, config)

        if self.username != None:
          addr.user = self.username+":"+self.passwd

        return SOAPpy.HTTPTransport.call(self, addr, data, namespace, soapaction, encoding, http_proxy, config)


if __name__ == '__main__':

  # code for authenticating the SOAP API calls
  myHTTPTransport.setAuthentication('admin', 'admin')

  # Getting the instance of Server
  Baton = SOAPpy.WSDL.Proxy(<WSDL PATH>, transport=myHTTPTransport)

  # your code goes here
  ...
```